# How to run Rscript persistently?

Tags: r

I have a file `Timer.R`, which I want to execute in a separate process from my interactive R session.

```
# In Timer.R
library(tcltk)
z <- function () { 
  cat("Hello you!\n") 
  .id <<- tcl("after", 1000, z)
}
.id <<- tcl("after", 1000, z)
tcl("after", "info", .id)   # To get info about this scheduled task
tcl("after", "cancel", .id) # To cancel the currently scheduled task
```

Trouble is, `Rscript` is not persistent - it terminates when it gets to the end of the file:

```
# In interactive session
system("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe Test.R", invisible = FALSE)
<Tcl> {R_call 00000000217CD078} timer 
<Tcl>  
> # Rscript has terminated by this point - timer is never run
```

Is there any way to keep `Timer.R` running persistently in the background?

Comment: What happens if you stick the 3 lines after the function definition into a `while(TRUE)` loop?

Comment: Thanks @Scott, but I simplified above and the actual code is substantially more complicated, so I can't just persist with a `while` loop. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. That's the approach I'd use in any other programming language too. Is there a way you can separate the logic so that you can put the Timer functionality into a `while(TRUE)` loop?

Comment: @Scott - hmmm tricky - I'm actually using the new process as a slave process that handles asynchronous tasks like streaming live data. My interactive R session will issue commands via a socket connection and the slave process executes them. However, because I may issue commands to the slave interactively, the slave must be launched in a persistent mode so that it can wait for commands.

Comment: Slightly different architecture would be to write the commands to a file (or some other stack implementation) by the master, read them with the slave and execute / delete. Then put the slave into a cronjob to run every minute.

Comment: why don't you use sockectConnection with blocking=TRUE to wait on command ?